# rvmsudo gem install capistrano

Tags: ruby, macos, rvmsudo

When running

```
rvmsudo gem install capistrano
```

I get this warning:

```
Warning: can not check `/etc/sudoers` for `secure_path`, falling back to call via `/usr/bin/env`, this breaks rules from `/etc/sudoers`. Run:

    export rvmsudo_secure_path=1

to avoid the warning, put it in shell initialization file to make it persistent.

In case there is no `secure_path` in `/etc/sudoers`. Run:

    export rvmsudo_secure_path=0

to avoid the warning, put it in shell initialization file to make it persistent.
```

I'm on Mac OS X and I've got no `secure_path` in `/etc/sudoers` so I assume I need to put:

```
    export rvmsudo_secure_path=0
```

in my `.bash_profile`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, based on the RVM warning, your `.bash_profile` is the correct place to put that export line.

Aside from that issue though, is using `rvmsudo` necessary? If you are using RVM you should be  able to install gems without sudo (because they are installing into your home directory, or a user writable system directory).

Comment: They are not installed in home directory if you do a system-wide install, which is what phusion passenger seems to recommend for production environments.

Comment: So are you using Mac OS X in production?